# Keeping the Rails console connected to activerecord?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, connection, rails-console

I'm following a tutorial that instructs me to put

```
    console do
      ActiveRecord::Base.connection
    end
```

In config/application.rb. Problem is this was intended for Rails 4. What's the equivalent on V5?

Comment: you can do ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection in rails 5

Comment: Just like that? No cosole do block?

Comment: You can execute that line after going to console